# Python requests using certificate value instead of path

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, certificate

I am using the python request module to makes a POST call:

```
import requests
response = requests.post( foo_url, 
                          json={"foo":"bar"}, 
                          headers=foo_headers,
                          verify='/path/to/cert' )
```

This works fine. Though is it possible to use the value of the certificate directly instead of the path to the file that contains the certificate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: The answer is definitively "no, the cert *must* be in a file on disk." And the reason why is because OpenSSL is awful.

`requests` is based on `urllib3`, which is based on `ssl`. `requests` takes your top-level `cert` parameter and splits it up into parameters named `cert_file` and `key_file`, which get passed to `urllib3`. `urllib3` passes them on, untouched, to `ssl`. And `ssl` expects them to be filenames.

The specific culprit at the bottom of the Python stack is [`SSLContext.load_cert_chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain) from the `ssl` module. It depends on `_SSLContext`, which is written in C. The C code for `_SSLContext.load_cert_chain` is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/18b711c5a7f90d88fb74748f18fa8ef49d8486c7/Modules/_ssl.c#L3891-L3912). And you can see, it really truly 100% needs a filesystem path! Ugh!

The culprit at the bottom of the C stack is OpenSSL's [`SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file.html), which has this signature:

```
int SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *file);
```

There are ways of building a cert chain in OpenSSL that don't involve "just open a file and read it in," but they're vastly more complicated, which I guess is why Python `ssl` doesn't use them... and that explains why `urllib3` doesn't use them, and that explains why `requests` doesn't use them.

Comment: *" And the reason why is because OpenSSL is awful."* - Late to the party, but ... the fault is not OpenSSL. It provides with [SSL_CTX_use_certificate](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_use_certificate.html) a way to load a certificate from a certificate object. This can be created from a PEM string by combining BIO_s_mem, BIO_write and PEM_read_bio_X509. And similar to the private key. May sound complex but its actually only a few lines of code. Did this ages ago for Perl IO::Socket::SSL.