# How to use an installed x509 Certificate as a Client certificate when programming a web request in python?

Tags: python, x509certificate, x509, client-certificates

I am working on a python script that is supposed to do web request using a client certificate from a store (so not from a file path). The certificate is already installed and the webrequest is already succeeding (when programmed in C# in a way similar to [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1uAhSt)).

My python code is failing and I do not know how to fix this.
Here is the failing code (the variables `url` and `in_subject` are set on top of the file).

```
import ssl
from cryptography import x509
import requests


def get_certificate(to_find_in_subject: str):
    for store in ["CA", "ROOT", "MY"]:
        for cert, encoding, trust in ssl.enum_certificates(store):
            certificate = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(cert, backend=None)
            if to_find_in_subject in f'{certificate.subject}':
                return certificate


certifcate = get_certificate(in_subject)
print(certifcate is None)
response = requests.request(method="GET", url=url, cert=certifcate)

print(response.text)
```

This is the output (shown below). Apparently, I cannot set the certificate as a certificate argument. That is not a big problem if I know what to do instead. So what is that, what to do instead? How to use an installed x509 Certificate as a Client certificate when programming a web request in python?

*False*

*Traceback (most recent call last):*

*File "C:\Users\daan\PycharmProjects\certificateCall\reproduceforStackoverflow.py", line 19, in*

*response = requests.request(method="GET", url=url, cert=certifcate)*

.........

*TypeError: 'builtins.Certificate' object is not subscriptable*

*Process finished with exit code 1*

Comment: This is from the documentation:
cert – (optional) if String, path to ssl client cert file (.pem). If Tuple, (‘cert’, ‘key’) pair.

What does get_certificate() yield?

Comment: @MenyIssakov That is most likely why it is failing but what should I do to make it work? I have a certificate from the store, not from a (pem) file.

Comment: I'm not certain if you have something to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203791/python-requests-using-certificate-value-instead-of-path

Comment: @MenyIssakov That is slightly different. What is asked is "value of the certificate directly instead of the path" . That is not my problem. My question is not about "value of the certificate" .  I have the full certificate object itself, not just the value and I already succeeded in using it in another dev language.

Comment: How about dumping it to disk to generate the cert file, and use that file as the variable?