# Using In-Memory SSL Certificates with Tornado in Python

Tags: python, ssl, tornado

I'm currently working on a Python project using Tornado and I need to secure the communication between the client and the server using HTTPS. However, due to the sensitive nature of the project, I want to avoid storing the SSL certificates as files on the disk.

I'm trying to load the SSL certificates directly from memory, but I'm encountering issues because the Python SSL module, which Tornado uses for SSL/TLS, expects the certificates and keys to be loaded from files.

Is there a way to load the SSL certificates from memory instead of from files? Or is there a workaround to this issue?

Comment: From my understanding [tornado.httpserver](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html) just takes an [SSLContext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext). Which means the question boils down on how to create a SSLContext with certificates from a string. Unfortunately SSLContext does not provide the necessary functionality.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404012/3081018